# What is the difference between "responseHeaders", "blocking", "asyncBlocking" in onAuthRequiredOptions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I am working on a project in which I have to login a BasicAuth website. I come across the document of [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and realize there are three different [onAuthRequiredOptions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-OnAuthRequiredOptions): namely "responseHeaders", "blocking",  "asyncBlocking".

I have tried them and the only thing I found out is that with "asyncBlocking", Chrome will let the extension has a chance to fire a callback, which can authenticate the BasicAuth, change the request header, e.t.c..

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  function(details, callback) {
    callback({
      authCredentials: {username: "login", password: "login"}
    });
  }, 
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['asyncBlocking']
);
```

But with "responseHeaders", "blocking", their behaviors seems to be the same, they both DO NOT have callback, but then I couldn't figure out the other differences.

I believe there is a reason for separating into three values. So I would like to know what is the philosophy behind them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `responseHeaders` permission is used to populate the optional property of `details` and is available in a couple of the methods. Without this permission, the headers that are received aren't available to the `webRequest` handler. As for `blocking` and `asyncBlocking` they are the same except one is synchronous and the other is not. `asyncBlocking` allows you to specify a callback like in your example, while `blocking` expects a `return` in the handler itself like so:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details) {
  return {authCredentials: {username: "login", password: "login"}};
}, 
{urls: ['<all_urls>']},['blocking']);
```